# Insert And Replace Query

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite

I am doing a task in which insert an amount in a database if the category already exist then replace and update the amount value only. I am using this query for inserting and replacing the value:

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO SpentAmount (CategoryName,CategoryIcon,Amount,Date,UserId)
Values ('House Rent','11','200','2018.07.09','9');
```

And in which only insert the value not any replace if the id already exists in database.

Comment: UserId is a primary key ?

Comment: Yes @Sh_Khan...

Comment: Thank You @Mat For Edit My Question I Am beginner In Ios Development And as Well As In StackOverFlow

Comment: @ShamDhiman: Only put uppercase letters at the start of sentences, not on every word. Your text is very hard to read otherwise.

Comment: i extremely Sorry @Mat

Comment: @ShamDhiman Make your `categoryname` field as unique. So when you insert the same category it will raise an exception, update your entry based on that. Or first run a select query and check whether that category is already present, if present update else insert

Comment: But How to Check and match categoryName With Database @MidhunMP